# What is the right way to calculate the median of a DataSet using Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

Let's say my DataSet is already sorted and looks like this:

```
[
   [100.0, 1],
   [105.0, 1],
   [111.0, 1],
   ... so on
]
```

The median equals 105.0! So in Java I got the DataSet Object containing the data:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<Double, Integer>> data = ...
```

Now is this the right way to calculate the median of the first element in the tuple?:

```
public double getMedian() throws Exception{
    DataSet<Tuple2<Double, Integer>> data = ...

    List<Tuple2<Double, Integer>> dataList = data.collect();

    double median = 0;

    // calculate median
    int itemCount = dataList.size();
    if (itemCount % 2 == 0)
        median = ((double) dataList.get(itemCount/2).f0 + (double) dataList.get(itemCount /2 - 1).f0)/2;
    else
        median = (double) dataList.get(itemCount/2).f0;
    return median;
}
```

I mean is this way a good one to run this code on a cluster?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Did you run the code? Does it produce the correct result? Is it too slow? What's the problem you want to solve? Note that asking for improvements without specific goals is off-topic on StackOverflow. If you want that there is a CodeReview StackExchange.

Comment: Hi, how did you implement the median eventially?